# facebook like is not posting to timeline/new feed/wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am getting one weird issue on my site. I did what facebook developer site said exactly the same way but still getting the same issue. Issue is that when I click on "Like" button on my website, the popup and count works absolutely fine but story does not get published on facebook's timeline or news feed. However (as strange it sounds) when I debug my page using linter tool it does not show any warnings and after that only like button for that page starts posting to user's wall otherwise not. I am not getting the connection between linter tool and this publish policy of FB. Can anyone please help me with this....it is taking too much time to resolve :(

These are my meta-tags

```
<meta property="og:description" content="[DESCRIPTION]" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="[SITE_ADDRESS]" />
<meta property="og:type" content="object" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="[PAGE_WHERE_LIKE_BUTTON_IS LOCATED]" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="[PAGE_TITLE]" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="[IMAGE_URL]" /> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="[APP_ID]" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="[ADMINS_ID]" />
```

I am using "Like" as action and "object" on my App Dashbord's opengraph.

The most strange thing is everything works fine onlt after using debug tool. Question is why??

BR,
MailMaster

Comment: I have the same problem here: http://www.organirama.com/minisite/single.php?p=Image_17.gif. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet. I have been posting on facebook forums also but yet no reply :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I temporary resolved calling the facebook debug tool directly from inside the page using an ajax call. It's horrible, I know. But if you are in a hurry (like me) you may want to use this as a temporary work around, until you find the right way

My page is http://www.organirama.com/showserver/minisite.php. The workaround is (requires jquery).:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.organirama.com%2Fshowserver%2Fminisite.php",
        success : function (a,b) {
        },
        error : function (a,b,c) {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: By the way, thanks for providing this temporary solution. This will surely help me from some manual work !

Comment: I am able to debug my link using this script...thanks...but still waiting for a concrete solution o_O